# Play! Could not execute java executable

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I upgraded my java compiler version to `javac 1.7.0_07`. The jre version is `1.6.0_27`.

I did the classpath settings and both the commands `javac -version` and `java -version` in command prompt are displaying the versions properly.

With this, when I try to run a Play Application, I am getting an error message in the console:

`Could not execute java executable. Please make sure JAVA_HOME environment is set properly.`

Is this because of the mismatch between the jdk and the jre versions? Or some other reasons?

Please let me know about this.

Thanks,

Comment: Post a `echo $JAVA_HOME`

Comment: JAVA_HOME should point to the directory where Java is installed in your system.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall the JDK/JRE and clean also you classpath/path and install the version you want to have

Make sure that JAVA_HOME is set to the location of your JDK, e.g. export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.* and that $JAVA_HOME/bin is in your PATH environment variable.